# Tailwind component library installed on Tailwind Website project experiencing class collision

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, tailwind-css

So, I've created a component library in React.js using Typescript. I'm using Tailwind CSS on this component library. I've published the component library on npm and then installed it on a website that I'm building. I'm trying to use Tailwind on my website as well. The problem is that when I apply Tailwind to the website and use the components, it is applying Tailwind to the component library a second time. Tailwind was already applied once to the component library when I built it. Now it is applying it a second time, and it's screwing things up like my sizing breakpoints. Here's an example of it being double applied to a component in my component library: [See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVdzw.png). How do I get Tailwind to ignore and not apply itself to my component library?

My initial idea was to see if there was a way to modify the css class names on build, but I haven't found any information on how to do that. Any ideas on how to fix this are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be best if you had a [prefix](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix) set up in your website tailwind config to avoid collision between your components library and website.

Comment: With new tailwind updates is there any better way? I have hundreds of class names already used in my site so using even a tiny prefix would be a pain to find and change every class name. Maybe at build time add prefix?

Comment: I have many ways to add a prefix to build time but there is no way to do it without creating problems. I solved it by setting a prefix and asking ChatGPT to insert the prefix into all tailwind classes in the project.